# php mail function, how to avoid hyperlink in the message

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

I'm using the php mail function and I have no problem sending the emails, I recieve well the emails on Hotmail and Gmail. But, when I wrote a web address in the message Gmail doesn't accepts the email because it arrives with an hyperlink, even though i'm writing the address in this way: "www.something.com" and I'm using Content-Type: text/plain; on the header.
I've tried to use strip_tags() with the message, but the problem persist.
What can I do?

Comment: Probably nothing its a feature of the clie

Comment: Sounds like it's the email client that's automatically converting it into a hyperlink as it recognises the format of a web address.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the code as follow:

```
<?php
$to = "to_email addrss";
$subject = "Your Subject";
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<a href='http://yourlink.com'>http://yourlink.com</a>
</body>
</html>
";


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@yoursite>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

?>

May be you failed to add content-type:text/html ,while sending your email address. may be this is the reason your anchor link it not working.hope this will work.